# Controlling number of tasks being executed at an instance at runtime

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, threadpool

I have been working on a (C#) project recently, using threadpool, and it was going well until a friend of mine briefly told me about TaskParallelLibrary(TPL).

Basically I was facing an issue of optimizing the performance of my program.

The thing is, I have quite a big list of tasks that are to be performed asynchronously. So, instead of running 1000s of tasks together and screwing up the whole machine, I inserted them in a queue using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and set the max threads that could be executed at a time to 4(having a quad core processor). But now, I want to use TPL since, I got to know it can manage the max and min threads running at an instance at runtime. This could be great to increase the performance of the program. But, now the main issue was how do I dynamically tell the TPL to find the maximum number of threads that can be executed, by analyzing the load on the processor, since there would be other programs running as well, instead of manually setting the max number of threads that can be executed?

This is my first question. If you could help me out, I'd highly appreciate! :)

**Edited**-->
My question seemed to be misunderstood, I'll explain it using an example ->
Say, I am writing some data to separate files in each task. And the total number of tasks are 10,000. Now this, is a huge number of tasks that cannot be executed simultaneously on a quad core processor. So, instead I create a queue and add up the tasks in it and TPL provides me some sort of scheduler that has a variable threshold value of executing n number of tasks at a single instance. Note: This n is variable and varies in accordance with the performance of the processor(as in the load on it).

So coming back to my question, is there any method in TPL, that automatically controls 'n' here, and keeps taking one task from the queue after one is completed until the whole queue is empty?

Comment: TPL does this automatically.

Comment: Could you send me a resource that could help me out with that or explain me a lil more in detail please? Thanks.....

Comment: Thanks for referring me to the link specifying working of tpl. But, in that existing question the answer doesn't refer to the dynamically deciding the number of tasks that can be executed at an instance. Rather, a semaphore is used to lock 20 tasks to run at a single time. My question is how can I make TPL decide that specific number.

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx